# I'm wondering why I'm getting a java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I'm getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` @ the start of the if here: `if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(passengers[i].getName()))`. This is when I enter a wrong name. There are a total of 500 passengers. Why? (This is only a small section of my code)

```
System.out.println("Booking Cancellation:");
System.out.println("--------------------");

name = null;
System.out.print("\nName of Passenger: ");
name = scan.nextLine();

for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{

   if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(passengers[i].getName()))
   {
        passengers[i].setName(null);
        passengers[i].setAddress(null);
        passengers[i].setEmail(null);
        passengers[i].setOnFlight(0);
        passengers[i].setFlightBooked(false);
        flights[i].decreaseBookedSeats();
        bookedSeatsOverall = bookedSeatsOverall - 1;

        System.out.println("\nPassenger's details have been wiped from the system.");
        System.out.println("The booking has been cancelled.\n");

        break;
    }else if (i == 499)
    {
         System.out.println("\nNo bookings have been made under this name.\n");
         break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Make sure `passengers` is well initialized before the loop.

Comment: can you write the code of getting the passengers?

Comment: Passengers array, where it is initialized?

Comment: Print out the values of `name`, `passengers[i]` etc to see precisely what is `null`

Comment: @DNA the problem could be also in `flights[i]`. @user636363 it would help much to show where is the error actually happening. It would help to point exactly where is the error than play the game **"here is a snippet of code, guess where is the error happening and how to fix it."**

Comment: You are getting the NullPointerException because you have a null pointer ("reference").  You know where it is, and there are only three pointers/references involved -- name, passengers, and the ith element of passengers.  It's a trivial matter to insert a println statement to print out those values and see which is null.  Or set a breakpoint in your debugger and examine them.

Comment: And it should be pointed out that if you go through the above code once, to "delete" one name, the next time through you will get a NullPointerException, because you'll encounter the null name you set the first time through.

Comment: @HotLicks removing one won't matter, as far as I know sending null to `.equals..` will return false. So it shouldn't matter. Also, `flights` and `flights[i]` could be `null`.

Comment: The OP claims he's getting the error on the `if` statement.  (And the OP is always right.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this guard:

```
if (name != null &&
    passengers[i] != null && 
    name.equalsIgnoreCase(passengers[i].getName()))
{
    //...code here
    if (flights[i] != null){
       flights[i].decreaseBookedSeats();
    } else {
       // should not happen
    }
    // .. more code
 }
```

You have to make sure than `name` isn't null. Since `nextLine` may return null it has to be checked. The `passengers[i]` and `flights[i]` check shouldn't be necessary but if anywhere in your code you might set one of those *cell* in the array to `null`, then you have to always check if they are null or not.

You could also check for `flights != null` and `passengers != null`. But honestly, you should be able to find out easily by printing values to console or using a debugger. NullReference exceptions are usually easy to find and fix.

Answer (score 0):

What is `passengers` ? Is it an array of length 500 ?

Is there a null passager in the array ?

Maybe the for loop can become

```
for (int i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
  if (passengers[i] != null && passengers[i].getName() != null) {
    ...
```

Comment: `name` and `flights[i]` could be null too.